# Miscellaneous characters in xmgrace

Tags: character, xmgrace

xmgrace is wonderful, but it has some problems when dealing with miscellaneous  characters.

How can I make the script small l (`$\ell$` in latex) in xmgrace?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to do this is to specify a script-like system font. None of the standard ones are suitable so you will have to make sure that a suitable font is installed on your system.

You can change to any font by enclosing the name in

```
\f{}
```

e.g.

```
\f{Symbol}
```

or

```
\f{Century-Schoolbook-L-Bold_italic}
```

You can see a list of the available fonts (and their labels) by going to the Font tool in the Window menu of the xmgrace GUI.

After typing the special character you can return to your original font in a similar way, or by using \0 to get back to the default font 0.